# How to fix Chromedriver failing on OS X Mavericks

Tags: node.js, selenium-chromedriver

I made the fun decision of upgrading to OS X Mavericks, and now I can't run chromedriver on my machine...

An easy way to replicate this is to create a new project with NodeJS, and install the wd package, then follow their instructions for running tests (this installs selenium and chromedriver).

wd: https://github.com/admc/wd#run-the-tests

I feel like this is settings issue, but am not even sure where to start... Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a statement, rather than a question? If they have an issue tracker, that would be the place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to help from sebv, developer of the NodeJS module I mentioned earlier, and located here: https://github.com/admc/wd

Here is the answer to the issue: https://github.com/admc/wd/issues/195

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=590

This has been logged.  The workaround is to run the chromedriver in verbose mode.  Some samples are in the comments there.